# How can I have a regex search and replace with space

Tags: python, regex

So I'm trying to get a regex to search for a screen name that can have a leading whitespace, wrapped in whitespace and a traling one. Right now this is what I have and it's working but it's an ugly solution:

```
# Start of text
self.tweet_text = re.sub(r'(?i)%s\s' % screen_name, profile_link + " ", self.tweet_text)
# One space before
self.tweet_text = re.sub(r'\s(?i)%s' % screen_name, " " + profile_link, self.tweet_text)
# Wrapped in spaces
self.tweet_text = re.sub(r'\s(?i)%s\s' % screen_name, " " + profile_link + " ", self.tweet_text)
```

Would It be possible to have all of these conditions in a single regex ?
I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: Maybe `\b` (word boundary) does something close enough to what you need.

Comment: I think you need whitespace boundaries. Use `r'(?i)(?<!\S){}(?!\S)'.format(screen_name)`